# Arraylist en java

Tags: java

¿Es posible que cuando uno cree un ArrayList este ya tenga un valor dentro de esta?

ejemplo:

```
//creo el arraylist para almacenar luchadores que son parte de otra clase
private ArrayList<Luchador> cantLuchadores= new ArrayList<Luchador>();
```

y que `cantluchadores.get(0)` ya tenga un luchador creado

Comment: Que tipo de datos contedra el arrayList?

Comment: El Luchador que quieres que se cree es aleatorio o siempre sería el mismo?

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2):

Desde Java 9 tienes el método [`of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of--) en la interfaz `List`. Te permite crear una lista **inmodificable** de elementos. El uso sería así:

```
private List<Luchador> cantluchadores = List.of(new Luchador(), new Luchador());
```

Tienes dos problemas con esto:

1. Tu variable cambia de ser de tipo `ArrayList` a ser de tipo `List`. Si usas métodos propios de `ArrayList` que no conformen con la interfaz `List`, tu código no compilará. Es cierto que se recomienda usar `List` mejor que `ArrayList` en la gran mayoría de casos, porque `List` suele tener todo lo que necesitas, por lo que no creo que te afecte.
2. La lista que devuelve el método es inmodificable, por lo que no podrás añadir ni quitar elementos *-sin embargo sí podrás modificar tus luchadores-* , si quieres tener una lista modificable, puedes hacer `new ArrayList<>(List.of(new Luchador(), new Luchador()));`

Answer (score 0):

### Lista que no cambie de tamaño

Otra alternativa en caso de que necesites tener una **lista parcialmente mutable** es usar el método estático [Arrays.asList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

```
List<Luchador> luchadores= Arrays.asList(new Luchador("El Santo"), new Luchador("El Cavernario"), new Luchador("Blue Demon"));
```

**El tamaño de tu lista no podrá cambiar**, pero puedes **remplazar los elementos** de tu lista usando el método set `java.util.ArrayList.set(int indice, E elemento)` .

Por ejemplo si quisieras remplazar al luchador "El Cavernario" por "El cavernario Galindo", podrías hacerlo algo así:

```
luchadores.set(1,new Luchador("El Cavernario Galindo"));
```

Este método debería de funcionar desde Java 7.

### Lista totalmente manipulable

Si deseas una lista que puedas **manipular totalmente** a tu antojo, puedes usar Stream y convertirlo a lista de la siguiente manera:

```
List<Luchador> luchadores = Stream.of((new Luchador("El Santo"), new Luchador("El Cavernario"), new Luchador("Blue Demon")).collect(toList());
```

y sin problemas podrías agregarle cualquier otro

```
luchadores.add(new Luchador("El Bulldog"));
```

Este método debería de funcionar a partir de Java 8.

### Lista modificable para versiones obsoletas

Existe otra forma tradicional de hacerlo **para versiones ya deprecadas** de Java pero te recomiendo **no usarla**, se le conoce como inicialización de doble llave, tiene el defecto de que te crea clases internas anónimas.

```
List<Luchador> list = new ArrayList<Luchador>() {{
            add(new Luchador("El Santo"));
            add(new Luchador("El Cavernario"));
            add(new Luchador("Blue Demon"));
}};
```

Answer (score -1):

La única opción que tienes es crear tu lista `cantLuchadores` a partir de otra colección, utilizando el constructor de la clase `ArrayList` que recibe como parámetro un tipo `Collection`.

```
private ArrayList<Luchador> cantLuchadores= new ArrayList<>(unaCollection);
```

De otro modo, la lista se creará vacía (sin elementos), lo que provocará que si tratas de acceder a una posición cualquiera (ej. `cantluchadores.get(0)`) se lance una excepción de tipo `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.